# ord() expected a character error

Tags: python, unicode

I'm writing a program that encodes and decodes a text chosen by the user. My decoder function seems to work fine when I input unicode codes to it to return the character but my encoder function is not working.

Simply put, what I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. ask the user if they want to encode or decode
2. if they want to encode, i want to gather a string of phrases until the user enters 'done', append them to the list, then encode them using my encode function, then finally print out the encoded list.
3. if they want to decode, i want to gather a series of intergers that are actually unicode codes until the user enters 'done', append them to list2, then decode them using my decode function and print out that decoded list.

Here is my code.

```
def encode(character):
    code = ord(character)
    new_code = code * 4 + 10 // 2

    return new_code

def decode(character):
    code2 = character * 2 - 10 // 4
    new_code2 = chr(code2)

    return new_code2

def main():
    encoded_list = []
    decoded_list = []

    choice = input('Hello! Do you want to encode or decode? ').lower()

    if choice == 'encode':
        text = input('Enter text to encode or "done": ')
        while text != 'done':
            encoded = encode(text)
            encoded_list.append(encoded)
            text = input('Enter text to encode or "done": ')

        if text == 'done':
            print(encoded_list)

    elif choice == 'decode':
        text2 = input('Enter characters to decode or "done": ')
        while text2 != 'done':
            text2 = int(text2)
            decoded = decode(text2)
            decoded_list.append(decoded)
            text2 = input('Enter characters to decode or "done": ')

        if text2 == 'done':
            print(decoded_list)

    else:
        print('Please enter a valid response')

main()
```

thanks so much!

Comment: Have you read your code yet?

Comment: Read your code. Talk through it.

Comment: ord takes a single character

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you have to encode each character of the string separately. The `ord` function can only take a **single** character, so instead of:

```
encoded = encode(text)
```

you want:

```
encoded = ""
for char in text:
    encoded += encode(text)
```

Also (this is unrelated to the error you're getting), you forgot to account for order of operations. You put `code * 4 + 10 // 2` instead of 
`(code * 4 + 10) // 2`, so the code is really equivalent to `code * 4 + 5`. You did a similar thing for decode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ord on each character of the string, not the whole string at once:

```
def encode(character):
    code = map(ord,character)
    new_code = [(x * 4 + 10) // 2 for x in code]
    return new_code

def decode(character):
    code2 = [(x * 2 - 10) // 4 for x in character]
    new_code2 = "".join([chr(x) for x in code2])
    return new_code2
```